# Unable to join chat channel

Tags: twilio

When trying to join a channel in the twilio code I've been working with, it comes up with the error saying that it "Cannot read property 'getChannelByUniqueName' of null". The chat works but when I try to open it up on a different browser, like firefox instead of chrome, it says the error "Channel with provided unique name already exist".  Can anyone help with this problem?

```js
    // Initialize the Chat client
    chatClient = new Twilio.Chat.Client(data.token);
    joinChannels(chatClient);
  });

  function joinChannels(chatClient) {
    chatClient.getSubscribedChannels();
    joinChannel('generalss','Generals Chat Channel');
  }

  function joinChannel(channelName, channelFriendlyName) {
    console.log(channelName);
    console.log(chatClient);
    print('Attempting to join "' + channelName + '" chat channel...');
    var promise = chatClient.getChannelByUniqueName(channelName);
    promise.then(function(channel) {
      console.log('Found ' + channelName + ' channel:');
      channels[channelName] = channel;
      console.log(channels);
      setupChannel();
    }).catch(function() {
      // If it doesn't exist, let's create it
      chatClient.createChannel({
        uniqueName: channelName,
        friendlyName: channelFriendlyName
      }).then(function(channel) {
        channels[channelName] = channel;
        setupChannel(channelName);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Where are you setting `chatClient`? Can you share a bit more of your code to show where you are setting up the client and how this function gets called?

Comment: @philnash I just updated the code I put in the questions to show chatClient

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks to me like you aren't passing the `chatClient` to your `joinChannel` method (and secondly that the client might not be fully initialised yet).

I would initialise the client with the following, which uses the `create` method that returns a promise that resolves when the Client is ready.

```
  // Initialize the Chat client
  new Twilio.Chat.Client.create(data.token).then(function(chatClient) {
    joinChannels(chatClient);
  });
});
```

Then, make sure you pass the client through to the `joinChannel` method:

```
function joinChannels(chatClient) {
  chatClient.getSubscribedChannels();
  joinChannel(chatClient, 'generalss','Generals Chat Channel');
}

function joinChannel(chatClient, channelName, channelFriendlyName) {
  // the rest...
}
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi, yes that helped. Thank you

Comment: Awesome, if it solved your issue, please do mark it as correct so that others can see too. Thanks!

Comment: I was wondering how I would go about instantiating a new client based on a user thats already created

Comment: Generate an access token for the user and use `new Twilio.Chat.Client.create(token)` to instantiate a new user.

Comment: I want to be able to create a user and then instead of always making a new user when I sign on, I want to be able to log into a specific user again. How would I go about that @philnash

Comment: Generating an access token is not logging on. You need to handle user login within your own application. When you have a logged on user, you assign them an identity to use within Chat, then you always generate that user's access tokens with that identity. That identity will have the same access to channels (public and private) that it did before.